# In Python - Can I access functions outside of a class not using inheritance or subclassing?

Tags: python

After creating an instance of a class. If there is a function (I am using function because in this case because it is outside of the class so not a method) that I define outside of the class, can I access it?

Comment: Did you try doing this and run into a problem? Post your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can access functions of another program/class/library by using an import...